# encog -difference between train.getError() and network.calculateError(dataset)

Tags: java, neural-network, training-data, encog

I have used both functions when training a network and both give approximately same values for each epoch. They are not exactly the same. I used network.calculateError(trainingdata).

What is the difference between getError() function and calculateError() function? 
Does getError() gives MSE for 1 epoch during training?

Answer (score 0):

`train.getError` Error is calculated BEFORE training is applied by the call to iteration. See the documentation here [BasicTraining.getError()](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/ml/train/BasicTraining.html#getError())

Whereas `network.calculateError()` calculates the error of the network using a regression calculator. This is why they will differ slightly.